# Alternative permutation notation (lines and bars)

Tags: group-theory, permutations, notation

I'm not quite sure whether this belongs here per se, but I remember reading online (it could well have been here on MSE or MO, but I think it might've been something on arxiv) some time ago about a kind of alternative notation for permutations consisting of vertical lines and horizontal lines between them. As I recall, one starts with $n$ vertical lines and then places horizontal bars between them at appropriate intervals, so that if one puts one's finger on the top of the $i$-th bar and traces out a path, going down and following whichever bar happens to be along the way, one winds up at $\sigma(i)$.
If I recall correctly, the origin was mentioned to have been Japanese, but I can't be sure about that. And what made it effective was the fact that for a product of permutations one can simply stick these diagrams together, one on top of the other, and in effect have the diagram for the product.

Has anyone here ever heard of or come across such a thing? I just remembered this the other day and thought it would be interesting to read about it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [ghost leg / amidakuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Leg):

[image]

Abstractly, a ghost leg is a diagrammatic way to describe a permutation as a composition of simple transpositions $(i, i+1)$. This particular set of generators makes the symmetric group into a [Coxeter group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group) and much is known from that theory about how to express permutations as such compositions.

Ghost legs are apparently used to randomly assign things (like prizes), which I find strange because the resulting distribution over permutations cannot possibly be uniform, although maybe it's close enough.

Similar diagrams called braid diagrams, incorporating crossings, appear in the theory of [braid groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group) and are a standard tool there:

[image]